# Codeigniter - add method URL & Redirect issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I have a method in CI which basically adds a user to a table - if any form validation occurs it reloads the view  - if successful it reloads the view to show that the user was added successfully. As seen below:

```
public function loadPeopleView(){
    //loads unit page view
    $this->load->model('people_model');
    $people['people'] = $this->people_model->getPeople();
    $this->load->view("header");
    $this->load->view("people page/people_view", $people);
    $this->load->view("footer");
}

public function addPerson(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('personName', 'personName', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[150]|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('personPet', 'personPet', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->load->model('');
        $this->people_model->addPerson();
        $this->loadPeopleView();
    } else{
        //if validation fails - returns the peopl view this display error messages
        $this->loadPeopleView();
    }
}
```

my issue is when someone adds a person the browser remains on:
localhost/peoplecontroller/addperson

if the user keeps refreshing the page - loads of people will continue to be added in - is there anyway I can put the page back to:
localhost/peoplecontroller/

without having to use a redirect as I still want any error messages from the form validation to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only giving you an example please arrange according save and return functionality

```
public function addPerson(){
    $this->load->model('people_model'); // load model
   // validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('personName', 'personName', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[150]|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('personPet', 'personPet', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
    // check validation not clear
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
         //if validation fails - returns the peopl view this display error messages
         // also set error dat back
        // setting up send back values to view
         $this->data['personName'] = $this->input->post('personName');
        $this->data['personPet'] = $this->input->post('personPet');
       // get this->data values as a variable in view like $personName
        // load view
        $this->load->view("header");
        $this->load->view("people page/people_view", $this->data);
        $this->load->view("footer");
    } 
    else{ // after validation success
       // do your saving db stuff and set success message in session flash and redirect to
        $this->people_model->addPerson();
        // get and show message flash in your view
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Please check card details and try again');
        redirect('results', 'refresh');

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems great for success but what about if the form validation fails?

Comment: use set_value or send data back to view and get

Comment: is this answer helpful for you?